# How do I navigate between these two lists?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm working on a test project. My goal is to be able to navigate from `HomeList` to `SampleDataList` and then to some different view that's based on the URL file type. I do not want to use Master/Detail.

With the code given below, I get the following error:

`Note: Links search for destinations in any surrounding NavigationStack, then within the same column of a NavigationSplitView. A NavigationLink is presenting a value of type "URL" but there is no matching navigationDestination declaration visible from the location of the link. The link cannot be activated.`

I have tried...

- Moving `navigationDestination(for:destination:)` to `HomeList`. This doesn't work.
- Embedding `SampleDataList` in a `NavigationStack`. This doesn't work either.
- Using a `NavigationPath`. I'm not sure I did this correctly, but it didn't work either.

---

```
    struct HomeList: View {
        
        var body: some View {
            NavigationStack {
                List {
                    NavigationLink {
                        SampleDataList()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Sample Data Picker")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    extension URL: Identifiable {
        
        public var id: Int { self.hashValue }
        
    }

    struct SampleDataList: View {
        
        var urls: [URL] {
            let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath!
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path).appendingPathComponent("SampleData")
            return try! FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
        }
        
        var body: some View {
            List(urls) { url in
                NavigationLink(value: url) {
                    Text("\(url.lastPathComponent)")
                }
            }
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            .navigationDestination(for: URL.self) { url in
                Text("\(url.lastPathComponent)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You only need 1 `NavigationStack` at the very top

Comment: @loremipsum Apologies. I posted the incorrect sample code and have fixed it with my edit. Either way, the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a solution using `NavigationPath`. I added a navigation path to `HomeList` and use an enum and `navigationDestination(for:destination:)` for navigating my static list...

```
struct HomeList: View {
    
    @State var path = NavigationPath()
    
    enum HomeListOptions: String, CaseIterable {
        case sampleDataPicker = "Sample Data Picker"
        // TODO: Add more cases here
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            List(HomeListOptions.allCases, id: \.self) { option in
                NavigationLink(option.rawValue, value: option)
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: HomeListOptions.self) { option in
                switch option {
                case .sampleDataPicker:
                    SampleDataList()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I kept my `SampleDataList` the same. It uses a `navigationDestination(for:destination:)` that handles URLs...

```
struct SampleDataList: View {
            
    var urls: [URL] {
        let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath!
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path).appendingPathComponent("SampleData")
        return try! FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        List(urls) { url in
            NavigationLink(value: url) {
                Text("\(url.lastPathComponent)")
            }
        }
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        .navigationDestination(for: URL.self) { url in
            Text("\(url.lastPathComponent)")
        }
    }
}
```